# Get multiple transformedSrc from a variant image

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I have a query:

```
query {
 productByHandle(handle: "${productHandle}") {
   variants(first: 3) {
     edges {
       node {
         title
         id
         priceV2 {
           amount
         }
         image {
           transformedSrc(maxWidth: 400)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which works great. However, I'm struggling to find the syntax to get **multiple transformedSrcs** from the variant image. I want to use this for an image srcset, so I'll need to have multiple sizes returned.

I'm new to GraphQL in general. I tried an array on the image, using an `AND` with multiple maxWidth and scale, duplicating the image piece, etc. I've also searched the Shopify API docs many times.

Is this just not possible for some reason, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also curious for answers and new to GraphQL. I seem to have had some success using aliases of `transformedSrc` in the query, see below. Not entirely sure if this is the correct way though. I'm surprised by the lack of info consider it's essential for fast loading sites.

```
query {
  collectionByHandle(handle: "archived") {
    products(first: 250) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          description
          tags
              images(first: 100) {
      edges {
        node {
          altText
          originalSrc
          smallImage: transformedSrc(maxWidth: 200, crop: CENTER)
          bigImage: transformedSrc(maxWidth: 400, crop: CENTER)
        }
      }
    }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm not sure when I'll be using GraphQL next, but I'll definitely reference back to this and try it then.

For now I will accept this answer. If someone else has a better solution in the future, I'll update :)

Comment: Had no idea how to actually make use of the "transformedSrc". Thank you!. It wasn't obvious to me from the docs. https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/products-and-collections/productvariant

Comment: @txyoji Shopify's docs are... special. Heck, when the media abilities (3D, video) first came out I reported multiple bits of incorrect info and deficiencies in them to my Shopify contact at the time. Though I got a "thank you" and was assured that the info was sent on to the appropriate team, let's just say I checked back a couple months ago and they still weren't updated.